# Spring Boot Keycloak - How to verify Bearer token?

Tags: spring, keycloak, bearer-token

Keycloak version 2.4.0_FINAL.

In my Spring Boot REST API, I want to verify bearer tokens in Keycloak.

I followed the following steps:

- http://www.keycloak.org/docs/2.4/securing_apps_guide/topics/oidc/java/spring-boot-adapter.html

I added the maven dependencies and the following to the application.properties.

```
keycloak.realm = realm
keycloak.auth-server-url = http://localhost:8080/auth
keycloak.ssl-required = external
keycloak.resource = app
keycloak.bearer-only = true
keycloak.credentials.secret = ...

keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[0].patterns[0] = /r/secure/*
```

What is the next step? According to me, this was the last step but it does not seem to do something.

**Update**
application.properties:

```
server.port = 8081
org.keycloak keycloak-tomcat8-adapter 2.4.0.Final
keycloak.realm = myapp
keycloak.auth-server-url = http://localhost:8080/auth
keycloak.ssl-required = external
keycloak.resource = mybackend
keycloak.bearer-only = true
keycloak.credentials.secret = ...
keycloak.use-resource-role-mappings = false

keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[0].name = secure
keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[0].patterns[0] = /r/secure/*
```

Comment: What is your question, what is not working?

Comment: When is keycloak verifying the token? I can still access the api without token, no feedback.

Comment: on which port is spring boot running and on which port keycloak?

Comment: spring boot at port 8081 (other than default)

Comment: keycloak 8080 btw

Comment: have you checked the answer below?

Comment: Yes, the first part is the same as I have. I added the ...[0].name and the org.keycloak dependeny. I don't have roles specified. My IDE marks keycloak.* as "Cannot resolve configuration property".

Comment: have you included the keycloak-tomcat8-adapter dependency?

Comment: application.properties: org.keycloak keycloak-tomcat8-adapter 2.4.0.Final. In pom.xml: <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-adapter</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-tomcat8-adapter</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: sorry dont know whats the problem. btw, you dont need org.keycloak keycloak-adapter... in the application.properties, only in pom.xml as dependency.

Comment: I have an example where I use keycloak spring-security adapter to set the security constraints by code rather than in application.properties. https://github.com/gmarziou/jhipster-keycloak/tree/master/service1 see MicroserviceSecurityConfiguration

Comment: I've got the spring security adapter + spring boot working all together properly. However, if your configuration is not working for you, you should do some debugging. Enable the logs for keycloak adapter (passing `logging.level.org.keycloak=DEBUG`) and see what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your security constraint must at least contain a role , i.e :

```
keycloak.security-constraints[0].securityCollections[0].authRoles[0]=admin
```

Be sure to add this role in keycloak and assign it to your user.

Comment: Thanks for the solution to this problem.

Comment: I now get this error on the server: NOT_ATTEMPTED: bearer only

Comment: Added new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43559997/spring-boot-keycloak-bearer-how-to-solve-not-attempted-bearer-only

Comment: I don't have enough SO reputation to comment on the other question but for some reasons your Spring Boot app doesn't think the http request is an XHR request

Answer (score 2):

You can solve your problem using spring security, if that's an option for you. I find it better. The instructions can be found [here](http://www.keycloak.org/docs/2.4/securing_apps_guide/topics/oidc/java/spring-security-adapter.html).

For example:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{
    super.configure(http);
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/customers*").hasRole("USER")
            .antMatchers("/admin*").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().permitAll();
}
```